# Using queryForList method of JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need to use the following query.

```
SELECT m.member_id, cardflag FROM member m, member_attribute ma WHERE m.member_number=:memberNumber AND m.ref_club_status IN ('A','S') AND m.member_id=ma.member_id
```

The datatype of `member_id` is byte array, and that of `cardflag` is varchar.

I need to use this query in my code, and looking at the options in jdbctemplate documentation, queryForList seems to be the best choice. I have been trying, but couldnt make out much as to how to pass the parameter to my query and also as to how to handle the return type.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is

```
String sql = "SELECT m.member_id, searscc FROM member m, member_attribute ma " +
            "WHERE m.member_number=:memberNumber AND m.ref_club_status IN ('A','S') AND m.member_id=ma.member_id";
String memberNumber = "John Doe";                   //the argument value for the sql above
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();     //replace this line with your own code to get JdbcTemplate instance.
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[]{memberNumber}) ;
byte[] tempMemberIds = null;
String tempSearscc = null;
if ((rows != null) || (rows.size() > 0)) {
    for (Map<String, Object> tempRow : rows) {
        tempMemberIds = (byte[])(tempRow.get("member_id"));     //key is your search field in your sql
        tempSearscc = (String)(tempRow.get("searscc"));
        //do your own jobs
    }
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Hope this useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @caoxudong.
But in the if condition did you mean `(rows!=null)` or is it `(rows==null)` itself?

Comment: @ramz  Oh oops, that's a typo, and I edited my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I also found that the query threw an exception because of the named parameter `:memberNumber` in it. It was dealt with by changing the named param to a plain `?`
Thanks again. Works fine.

Comment: Just a minor suggestion use !rows.isEmpty(), this is better than calling the checking the size.      if(rows!=null && !rows.isEmpty()){}

Comment: Is there a "cleaner" way of retrieving the fields instead of casting the return value of get()?